# Input a date in 8 digit numerical form and display into English form

Tags: c++, list

Below is the c++ problem i have to solve and i'm having some trouble from number 2)

1) Prompt the user to input a date in 8 digit numerical form(MMDDYYYY)
ex. 04221970

2) Display the date in English form
ex. 22nd April 1970

3) If the day the user entered is 01,21,31, add "st" after the day

4) Else if the day the user entered is 02,22, add "nd" after the day

5) Elae if the day user entered is 03,23, add "rd" after the day

6) Else add "th" after the day

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Dean. We are here to help you with your programming questions, issues or frustrations. So please tell us what is your trouble with number 2? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

All of the step are rather straightforward.  But dates are always tricky, since there are many rules.  But only a couple apply for parsing.

Define a struct to hold the parsed value and parse the input.

[EDIT] The value of using a struct, is that it can be useful to have an intermediate function that would return this reusable bit of binary data.

```
struct date_s
{
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int year;
};

// parsing 
date_s date = {};
if (strlen(input) != 8 || sscanf(input, "%2u%2u%4u", &date.month, &date.day, &date.year) != 3)
{
    // handle error
}
```

Validating the year is rather easy, there is nothing to do, unless you want to restrict to a specific range.  For example, since we're using the Gregorian calendar, you may want to restrict to years after 1582, inclusive.

Validating the month is also very straightforward, we'll validate that along with the number of days in a month, which is the most tricky part, because of Febuary.

```
unsigned int day_max = 0;
switch (date.month)
{
case 1: case 3: case 5; case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
     day_max = 31;
     break;

case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
      day_max = 30;
    break;

case 2:
     if (date.year % 4 != 0)
         day_max = 28;
     else if (date.year % 100 != 0)
         day_max = 29;
     else if (date.year % 400 != 0)
         day_max = 28;
     else
         day_max = 29;
     break;

// else day_max stays 0, of course
}

if (date.day < 1 || day_max < date.day)
{
    // error
}
```

After all the validating is done, all you have to do is print.

For the months you will need to define a table of strings for display.

```
const char* MONTH[12] = { "January", /* etc... */ };
```

Date suffix.

```
const char* SUFFIX[4] = { "st", "nd", "rd", "th" };
```

We now have all the data we need to print, and all within range, too.

```
const char* suffix = SUFFIX[std::min(date.day, 4) - 1];

printf("%d%s %s %d", date.day, suffix, MONTH[date.month - 1], date.year);

// or, for US format
printf("%s %d%s, %d", MONTH[date.month - 1], date.day, suffix, date.year);
```

Comment: Because I'm a professional.  Your regex solution sure is an interesting exercise, BUT:

1. Professionals don't have 4 hours to give to examine nor debug miles long regex expressions.  Especially on weekends.

2. The OP will certainly not be able to debug it nor explain to his teacher what that regex expression works, in the foreseable future?  In fact, I would strongly advise the OP not to present your regex if he wants to avoid a failing grade.

3. I'm sure the code I've proposed is more efficient, will work on any device, and will pass any code review.

Comment: 4. There are a certain number of famous date/time bugs in computer science History, that could have easily been avoided  if some programmer had avoided trying to show off skills that are not required for the task..

Comment: 5. If the OP must use std::string for HIS assignment, he should know what to do.  What I mean is that this site is intended to help, It's not about doing someone else's schoolwork.  Our industry needs engineers who have done their homework, there are enough terrible developpers out there as it is.  Please not take this last bit personally. I am simply stating a fact.  Your regex solution _is_ an interesting exercise, but I am not the only one who would not trust that kind of solution in production code, when there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: I understand the regex, I also understand it takes skill, and a lot of care to write and debug regex strings.  They certainly have their use, but not in such a low-level function.  As for the use of sscanf(), yes, it would pass for a low-level function like this one.  Show me another way in C++ to check and parse a string in one line of code that's very readable, easy to reason about, will not throw, doesn't rely on a third-party library, and is as fast or faster, Then I will change my mind. The C library will always be part of C++ for very good reasons.